# data frame from character vector that contains three comma seperated values in each row

Tags: r

How to create columns of a data frame from a long character vector that contains three comma seperated values in each row. The first element contains the names of the data frame columns.

Not every row has three columns, some places there is just a trailing comma:

```
> string.split.cols[1] #This row is the .names
[1] "Acronym,Full form,Remarks"
> string.split.cols[2]
[1] "AC,Actual Cost, "
> string.split.cols[3]
[1] "ACWP,Actual Cost of Work Performed,Old term for AC"
> string.split.cols[4]
[1] "ADM,Arrow Diagramming Method,Rarely used now"
> string.split.cols[5]
[1] "ADR,Alternative Dispute Resolution, "
> string.split.cols[6]
[1] "AE,Apportioned Effort, "
```

The output should be a df with three columns, I'm only interested in the first two columns and will throw out the third.

[image: R is awesome]

This is the original string, some columns are not comma escaped but that isn't a big huge deal.

string.cols <- `[1] "Acronym,Full form,Remarks\nAC,Actual Cost, \nACWP,Actual Cost of Work Performed,Old term for AC\nADM,Arrow Diagramming Method,Rarely used now\nADR,Alternative Dispute Resolution, \nAE,Apportioned Effort, \nAOA,Activity-on-Arrow,Rarely used now\nAON,Activity-on-Node, \nARMA,Autoregressive Moving Average, \nBAC,Budget at Completion, \nBARF,Bought-into, Approved, Realistic, Formal,from Rita Mulcahy's PMP Exam Prep\nBCR,Benefit Cost Ratio, \nBCWP,Budgeted Cost of Work Performed,Old term for EV\nBCWS,Budgeted Cost of Work Scheduled,Old term for PV\nCA,Control Account, \nCBR,Cost Benefit Ratio, \nCBT,Computer-Based Test, \n..."`

Comment: Have you looked at `read.csv` or `readr::read_csv` or `data.table::fread`?

Comment: I don't want to use files it's a string, I get this error with `a <- fread(string.split.cols, header = TRUE)`: 'input' must be a single character string containing a file name, a command, full path to a file, a URL starting 'http[s]://', 'ftp[s]://' or 'file://', or the input data itself. Seems like it should work but I don't know.

Comment: If the `text` parameter of `read.csv` isn't enough, use `paste` with `collapse = '\n'` to deal with it as a single text string, which most reader functions can handle, e.g. `readr::read_csv(paste(x, collapse = '\n'))` or `data.table::fread(paste(x, collapse = '\n'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the text input for `read.csv`?

```
df <- read.csv( text = string.split.cols, header = T )
```

Comment: `header = TRUE` is the default for `read.csv`, so you don't really have to specify.

Comment: @alistaire yes, I just wanted to make the process clear for the OP, since the fact that the first row contains the "names" was explicitly pointed out.

Comment: This method is not perfect, it creates problems where there are words like this: `[109] SWOT Strengths, [110] Opportunities and Threats, [111] T&M Time and Material` but I have to examine the original string, maybe there were commas in there. It is good for 99% of my rows so I can use it. Ah, I see, there were commas in the second column SWOT, Strenghts\,Opportunities\,Weakenesses\,Threats and it splits on them because they are not escaped.

Comment: You can specify the `colClasses` in the call. Does that help?

Comment: Do you mean because those lines have too few commas?

Comment: Some lines contains commas in the second column that are not escaped. I should go back to my original string and split on the newline and tab characters instead of creating commas unless there is a way to split only on the first commas.

Comment: Yep, that's gonna be a problem. Another way would be to enclose each "cell" in quotations, that way `read.csv` will consider those commas part of the cell, rather than as a separator.

Answer (score 1):

I found this routine to be very fast for splitting a string and converting to a data frame.

```
slist<-strsplit(mylist,",")
  x<-sapply(slist, FUN= function(x) {x[1]})
  y<-sapply(slist, FUN= function(x) {x[2]})
  df<-data.frame(Column1Name=x, Column2Name=y, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

where `mylist` is your vector of strings to split.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rbind.data.frame` to do this, after splitting the string:

```
x <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(split.string.cols[-1], ','))
names(x) <- strsplit(split.string.cols[1], ',')[[1]]
x
##  Acronym                     Full form         Remarks
## 1      AC                   Actual Cost                
## 2    ACWP Actual Cost of Work Performed Old term for AC
## ...
```

As a one-liner:

```
setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, 
                 strsplit(split.string.cols[-1], ',')
         ),
         strsplit(split.string.cols[1], ',')[[1]]
)
```